# Issue with clicking link on selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I tried everything. By xpath , by css-selector , by class name too.

```
//*[@id="opbox-listing"]/div/div/section[2]/section/article[5]/div/div/div[2]/h2/a
thats look xpath , but don't work
```

on selenium i tried thats way:

```
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=opbox-listing']/div/div/section[2]/section/article[5]/div/div/div[2]/h2/a")).submit();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=opbox-listing']/div/div/section[2]/section/article[5]/div/div/div[2]/h2/a")).click();
```

what i do wrong? someone have any ideas?

Comment: Use the developer console in Chrome to test your xpath by putting in `$x("your xpath here")`. If it doesn't work there, there's a problem with your xpath. If it works, then there could be an iframe or another issue (long xpaths like that are pretty fragile).

Comment: @DeanW. in chrome my xpath works , in selenium nope..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out clicking on the element using one of following methods

**Method 1:**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(<your WebElement>).click().perform();
```

**Method 2:**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", <your WebElement>);
```

These are just workarounds. Please provide the exception that you are getting while performing the normal selenium click operation may be that can help you find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your xpath is broken: opening apostrophe is missing for an `id` value:

```
"//*[@id='opbox-listing']/div/div/section[2]/section/article[5]/div/div/div[2]/h2/a"
```

Comment: okay , i fixed it , but still is the same problem , maybe you look on site ? https://allegro.pl/listing?string=brama&order=p&bmatch=sa-base-relevance-floki-5-nga-hou-1-2-0511

Comment: Try another xpath: `//div[@id='opbox-listing']//h2//a[contains(.,'<YOUR TEXT HERE>')]` - just insert necessary link text (may be partial text).

Comment: Your initial xpath being fixed with apostrophe should work. THe problem may be in that the page is not loaded fully while you are trying to click this element. Look into [explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Comment: text change name after 5-6 times site refresh